# Restart terminal & run command using Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, nvm

I have a Dockerfile where I am installing nvm. After installation, i'll be needing to install node 5.11 using nvm. The problem is, after installing nvm, the terminal needs to be closed & run again in-order to to have nvm command available.

My docker file looks like:

```
# Installing Node
RUN Y | curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.2/install.sh | bash
# RUN bash --login
RUN exec bash
RUN nvm install 5.11.0

# Installing Project dependencies
RUN npm install yarn -g
RUN npm install -g webpack@1.13.2
```

And the output I am getting is :

```
Step 5/9 : RUN exec bash
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cfcdc4c98714
Step 6/9 : RUN nvm install 5.11.0
 ---> Running in 1874de4a7715
/bin/sh: 1: nvm: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c nvm install 5.11.0' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

In real linux after running `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.2/install.sh | bash` after closing & starting the terminal the nvm command gets available. How do I do it in dockerfile? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `SHELL ["bash", "-lc"]` in your dockerfile and that should do the job for you

Comment: It did, but npm install command it is giving me:

Step 7/9 : RUN npm install yarn -g
 ---> Running in 21bd1e67bb99
stdin: is not a tty
bash: npm: command not found
The command 'bash -lc npm install yarn -g' returned a non-zero code: 127

I added by new npm install commands in the post now.

Comment: Can you update the complete build log?

Comment: @YeasinHossain I'm dealing with the same issue! The same output after adding `SHELL ["bash", "-lc"]`.

Comment: The only difference is that I was installing `anaconda`

Answer (score 3):

Every new **RUN** command creates a new layer in docker image, so you can treat it as a new terminal spawns for each "RUN".

What seems to be the problem: when running a command in this way: piping it through bash `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.2/install.sh | bash` **it won't throw any errors if something fails.**

Had a similar issue a few weeks ago. Does your base image have all the dependencies? Depending of the base image, before running the script from github add a **RUN** task which will download **curl wget ca-certificates**. You can lookup how other people install nvm on their images: https://github.com/mikeyfarrow/docker-nvm/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

Has commands can do this.
`PATH="$PATH"` and `exec bash`
So, you can add these command inside your dockerfile.
If `exec bash` not work.Try another one.
It's work for me !

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following to restart the terminal in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN bash -c "source ${HOME}/.bashrc"
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use a [prebuilt node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) that has the right version of node.js installed already.

You don't need tools like nvm (rvm, virtualenv, ...) when you already have the Docker image as an isolation layer from other software that might be installed on the host; you'd never install multiple versions of a language runtime in a single image, where you might need to on a desktop or developer system.

Comment: You might be using a base image for your backend stack but need to install a specific node version as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If they user wants to install Node in their docker image, rather than using the node image, is irrelevant.